# how to set docker memory for large query response on docker container

Tags: docker

I have nodejs application hosted on docker container that is on AWS EC2 ubuntu server. Whenever, I have query send out to retrieve a large json object response. My application crashed on docker container whenever memory usage reach around 2.5G and error message print out as following. I try to rebuild my application with **docker run --memory=16G** same issue still happen. Anyone have suggestion or hint how i can resolve it?

```
CONTAINER ID        NAME                       CPU %               MEM USAGE / LIMIT     MEM %               NET I/O             BLOCK I/O           PIDS
7ef4100a978f        test_app_a                 112.55%             316.1MiB / 16GiB      1.93%               603MB / 31.5MB      111kB / 17.6MB      43
50a79dc738c5        test-app_b                 0.04%               98.28MiB / 31.42GiB   0.31%               806B / 0B           12.4MB / 2.18MB     30

error from application log
<--- JS stacktrace --->

==== JS stack trace =========================================
FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
 1: node::Abort() [/app/versions/node/v6.9.1/bin/node]
 2: 0x1098b2c [/app/versions/node/v6.9.1/bin/node]
 3: v8::Utils::ReportApiFailure(char const*, char const*) [/app/versions/node/v6.9.1/bin/node]
 4: v8::internal::V8::FatalProcessOutOfMemory(char const*, bool) [/app/versions/node/v6.9.1/bin/node]
 5: v8::internal::Factory::NewRawTwoByteString(int, v8::internal::PretenureFlag) [/app/versions/node/v6.9.1/bin/node]
 6: v8::internal::Runtime_SparseJoinWithSeparator(int, v8::internal::Object**, v8::internal::Isolate*) [/app/versions/node/v6.9.1/bin/node]
 7: 0x32fd39f092a7
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

Comment: run your container on ecs with servless if such heavy query need to run.instead of ec2

Comment: any other solution I can set up docker memory usage? i cannt really change ec2 to ecs